# Files used by mount

Tags: linux

/dev/md1               6068992   5204648    551080  91% /

I have 91% taken and am trying to discover what files are taking up space.  I'm using linux.  Does any one know the command?

thanks

Comment: This seems like a dupe of [Tracking down where disk space has gone on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230/)

Answer (score 9):

`du -k -S -x / | sort -n -r | head -10`

Will return the 10 largest files on the root file system.

Edit: @[Alnitak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782/alnitak)'s answer included the `-S` and `-x`, included here for completeness.

Answer (score 9):

This will list the directories in (reverse) order of size

```
# du -k -S -x / | sort -r -n
```

Note:

- `-S` tells it not to include subdirectory counts, so each directory figure will be the use of **that** directory, not the tree below it
- `-x` tells it not to leave that file system.  Without this it'll go into `/proc`, `/dev`, `/sys`, etc, and you don't need to `du` those.

EDIT: doh!  didn't mean the --max-depth=1 - just force of habit!

Comment: +1:  "-S" and "-x" are nice improvements.  `du` on `/proc` doesn't hurt anything - just more nodes to filter out, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` to locate the largest files on your system, for example:

```
find / -size 100M -print
```

Will find and print the names of all files that are 100 MB or larger.  You can use the `-mount` option if you only want to look in the partition that the specified directory resides on:

```
find / -mount -size 100M -print
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use:

```
du -x / | sort -ns
```

But when on the GUI you can also use [filelight](http://www.methylblue.com/filelight/) or [fsview](http://docs.kde.org/kde3/en/kdeaddons/konq-plugins/fsview/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Often it is not the size of a single file but what is contained in the subdirectories.  I usually use the `--max-depth=1` option to `du` to find the "big directories" in my `home`.  Everything outside of `home` is installed in some way, so I can go to my package manager and let it show all installed packages, sorted by disk size; then I can throw out some things I do not need anymore.